# How do I send a parameter to an iframe on another page?

Tags: wordpress, iframe

I'm trying to integrate TrackerRMS on my WORDPRESS website. On the main jobs page, I have an iframe that produces a listing of jobs.

```
<iframe frameborder="0"
  scrolling="yes"
  width="1000"
  height="780" 
  src="https://evoportalus.tracker-rms.com/mycompany/jobs?
  theme=purplehaze
  &fields=title,worktype,location,salaryfrom,salaryto,sector,joblink
  &joblinkuri=http://example.com/jobs-detail&joblinktarget=_parent&filters=">
</iframe>
```

Once displayed, there is a button on the page with a link to apply for that job is in this format:

http://example.com/jobs-detail?jobcode=1234

The problem is that I need to be able to pass the number, 1234, into this iframe code, on the jobs-detail page.

```
<iframe frameborder="0"
  scrolling="no"
  width="100%"
  height="700"
  src="https://evoportalus.tracker-rms.com/mycompany/jobs
  ?theme=purplehaze
  &fields=reference,title,location,worktype,description,linkregister
  &filters=reference|JOBCODE-NUMBER-NEEDS TO APPEAR HERE">
</iframe>
```

What do I need to add to the second iframe code on the jobs-detail page to grab the jobcode number from the URL, and append it after the "reference|"?

Note again, this is a Wordpress site, so I'm just using a shortcode to insert raw HTML code onto the page.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this works, by adding this code to the jobs-detail page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    loadSite();
function getQueryString (field, url) {
    var href = url ? url : window.location.href;
    var reg = new RegExp('[?&]' + field + '=([^&#]*)', 'i');
    var string = reg.exec(href);
    return string ? string[1] : null;
};
function loadSite() {
    var site = "https://evoportalus.tracker-rms.com/mycompany/jobs";
    site += "?theme=purplehaze&fields=reference,title,location,worktype,description,linkregister&filters=reference|" + getQueryString("jobcode");
    console.log(site);
    document.getElementById('trmsjobs').src = site;
}
```